# Can I use Devise to solve the N+1 problem? Ruby on Rials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models, Article(belong_to User) and User(has_many Articles). Using Devise to get the current logged in user, and then fetching the articles (sorted from most recent) of that user, am I solving the N+1 problem?
For example:
`@articles = current_user.articles.sort('created_at DESC')`
And then list the article's title with the author in the view as follows:

```
@articles.for_each do |article|
    <p>article.title</p>
    <p>article.author.name</p>
end
```

The way I understand it is that it finds the user who's logged in then finds the articles belonging to that user. As opposed to finding all the articles:
`@articles = Article.all.sort('created_at DESC')`
And then the ORM has to do another query to find the author associated with that article.

I know I'm able to use `include`, but I am curious if this is a viable solution.

Comment: dude. if you are taking the articles of current_user , it will always show the author name as current_user's name. You can do `@articles = Article.includes(:author).all.order(created_at: :desc) `

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware that I'm able to do `<p>current_user.name</p>`. But does does my solution solve the N+! problem? Without having to use include? @Vishal

Comment: It should not create N + 1 queries if you are taking `current_user.name`. If you want to avoid calling the `current_user` method every time. just store it in variable in action `@author_name = current_user.name` . use this variable in view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve `articles` from `Article` model that have `current_user` scope without using `includes` maybe you could do this:

```rb
@articles = Article.where(user: current_user).order(created_at: :desc)
@articles.each{|article| article.user = current_user }
```

or

```rb
@articles = current_user.articles.order(created_at: :desc)
@articles.each{|article| article.user = current_user }
```